# HockeyApp Xamarin.Android CrashManager Description

Tags: android, xamarin.android, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I have 2 activities, activity A and activity B.
In both activities I have registered the crash manager like this:

```
CrashManager.Register(this, MyID, new CustomCrashManagerListener());
```

Where in CustomCrashManager I have override the get Description method to be different in activity A from activity B.

My question is: If an exception happened in Activity B, I always get the activity A Description, how I can get the activity B Description?

Thank you.

Comment: I saw your question is answered in [HA forum](https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/72068-crashmanagerlistener-description-for-android-os), maybe you can have a check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I did it:

I did this once in my first activity, I created crash manager listener class

```
private class AppCrashManagerListener : CrashManagerListener
        {

            public override string Description
            {
                get { return MyCustomDescription(); }
            }
        }
```

Then in OnCreate method:

```
CrashManager.Register(this, HockeyAppId.AndroidId, new AppCrashManagerListener());
```